# bbfreeze picks wrong python path

Tags: python, python-2.7, freeze

After upgrading to ActivePython 2.7.5.6 from ActivePython 2.7.3, bbfreeze fails with several import errors, e.g.  `ImportError: cannot import name MAXREPEAT`. I traced the issue and it is with wrong Python version/installation picked by bbfreeze. It is weired that currently there are two system Python installations:

```
bash-3.2$ python
Python 2.4.3 (#1, Jun 11 2009, 14:09:37) 
[GCC 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-44)] on linux2
```

and:

```
ash-3.2$ /usr/bin/python2.7
Python 2.7 (r27:82500, Sep 24 2010, 08:01:50) 
[GCC 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-46)] on linux2
```

and a local installation:

```
bash-3.2$ ActivePython-2.7/bin/python   
ActivePython 2.7.5.6 (ActiveState Software Inc.) based on
Python 2.7.5 (default, Sep 16 2013, 23:05:39) 
[GCC 4.0.2 20051125 (Red Hat 4.0.2-8)] on linux2
```

but embeded python compler in bbfreeze give a different one, i.e. none of a bove:

```
bash-3.2$ bin/py
Python 2.7.1 (r271:86832, Dec  5 2010, 11:36:33) 
[GCC 4.0.2 20051125 (Red Hat 4.0.2-8)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
(MyConsole)
```

I even don't know where this Python 2.7.1 is installed! Any idea how to force bbfreeze to use the local python directory. I already used virtualenv, but didn't work.

Thanks.

@AsoAgile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I downgraded ACtivePython to 2.7.3 and reinstalled bbfreeze and it worked. So bbfreeze turned out to be not supporting ActivePython 2.7.5.